# How can I decompile Linux binaries from Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, binaryfiles, decompiler

How can I decompile Linux binaries (*.so) from Windows? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/); you will need to build it first from source as the provided binaries don't cover this case. If you absolutely refuse to compile anything, try the binary distribution for Linux and run it in a virtual Linux machine on Windows.

Comment: I recently *tried* to compile `boomerang`, and I could have started had I littered my box full of includes/headers.  It uses the ML version of the "New Jersey Machine Code Toolkit", plus a good handful of other intense dependencies.  To top it off it looks like the project has not progressed in multiple years.  The best part is this line from the FAQ " ... That means that until this is implemented, then without significant manual guidance, Boomerang can't even decompile its own test/windows/hello.exe"

Comment: The commercial world has plenty of high quality decompilers, it is frankly depressing to see what the FOSS world offers.  To make matters even worse, the freeware decompilers available are barely usable.