# Is there any way to decompile Linux .so?

Tags: c++, c, linux, decompiler, shared-libraries

Is there any way to decompile Linux .so?

Comment: Is the source not available for the library you are looking to reverse engineer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558370/how-can-i-decompile-linux-binaries-from-windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168794/how-to-view-source-code-of-dll-files/2168826#2168826

Comment: There is. but I want to try it on some with no source to - just for fun...=)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are [decompilers](http://www.backerstreet.com/decompiler/decompilers.htm), but a decompiler might not emit code in the same language that the original program was written in.

There are also [disassemblers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers), which will reassemble the machine code into assembly.

---

**[The Decompilation Wiki](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/DeCompilation)** may be a good source of additional information.

Answer (score 16):

You can disassemble the code with [`objdump(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) for example.