# Linux Decompile .so Files

Tags: linux, unix, command, decompiler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to decompile Linux .so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306972/is-there-any-way-to-decompile-linux-so)

Is there any way we can decompile an .so file ?

I already have the dissemble but how i can re-compile it?