# How to get source code of .so file in android

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

I want to see source code of shared object library (so) file in android. how can i convert .so binary file to native c/c++ code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306972/is-there-any-way-to-decompile-linux-so

Comment: The source is not part of binary files. You can *decompile* the binary code, but it will not be the original source code, and will not really be readable.

Comment: In general you can't.

Comment: You may not know that Android is built on top of Linux.  So you're, in effect, asking to decompile a Linux so file.  That's why link by @iosdude is relevant.  You might also check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205059/is-there-a-c-decompiler

Comment: a dis-assembler application would give you assembly code, but nothing will go back to the original c (or c++) code

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of making an so file is to NOT share the source code, no matter if it is android or not.
This is intentionally designed this way so as not to open the design. 
Following this, many firms share .so file (machine instructions) keeping their design confidential.

However, if you are keen to know what the .so file contains, you may read the ELF (Executable and Linkable Format) of the library. 
command

`readelf -a yourLibraryName.so > yourLibraryName_elf.txt`

The output contains symbol table. You may search for the function names, global variables etc from the generated text file.

More details of the contects here http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf